# How do you run a global plugin's shell in CakePHP 2?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.6

- I have a shell located in `PluginName/Console/Command/FooShell.php` in CakePHP 2.6.3.
- I've loaded this plugin via `CakePlugin::load('PluginName');` in my app's `bootstrap.php`.
- When that plugin is in `ROOT/app_name/Plugin`, and I run `PluginName.foo`, **the shell works**.
- When that plugin is in `ROOT/plugins` and I run the same command, **I get an error**:

The command:

```
    C:\xampp\htdocs\site_name\app_name>php Console/cake.php -app app_name PluginName.foo
```

The error:

```
    Warning Error: include(C:\xampp\htdocs\site_name\app_name\Plugin\PluginName\Console\Command\FooShell.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in [C:\xampp\htdocs\site_name\lib\Cake\Core\App.php, line 547]

    Warning Error: include(): Failed opening 'C:\xampp\htdocs\site_name\app_name\Plugin\PluginName\Console\Command\FooShell.php' for inclusion (include_path='C:\xampp\htdocs\site_name\lib;.;C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in [C:\xampp\htdocs\site_name\lib\Cake\Core\App.php, line 547]

    Error: Shell class FooShell could not be found.
    #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\site_name\lib\Cake\Console\ShellDispatcher.php(200): ShellDispatcher->_getShell('PluginName.back...')
    #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\site_name\lib\Cake\Console\ShellDispatcher.php(66): ShellDispatcher->dispatch()
    #2 C:\xampp\htdocs\site_name\app_name\Console\cake.php(33): ShellDispatcher::run(Array)
    #3 {main}
```

For some reason, CakePHP is fine with this plugin being in `ROOT/plugins` when it's serving actual webpages, but throws an error in the console.

Nothing in the [shell docs](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/console-and-shells.html) or the [plugin docs](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/plugins/how-to-use-plugins.html) explicitly says that there's anything different about using plugins in `ROOT/plugins`, but discussion of how that directory is used is conspicuously absent from the plugin and [folder structure docs](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/getting-started/cakephp-folder-structure.html). (I assume because it's implied you're supposed to implement plugins the same way, regardless of which directory they're in.)

Am I doing this wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when it is in the `ROOT/plugins` directory you need to load it like this in `ROOT/lib/Cake/bootstrap.php`

```
App::build(array('Plugin' => array(CAKE . DS . 'plugins' . DS)));
CakePlugin::load('<plugin-name>');
```

Comment: That did the trick, at the expense of that icky feeling you get when you modify the core files. Thanks!

Comment: You should also be able to do the same thing in `ROOT/app_name/Config/bootstrap.php`, which is part of your app, not the Cake core. That's one of the earliest files loaded, so as long as your `App::build()` declaration is before your `CakePlugin::load()` it should work fine.